# Problem while Installing The Homestead Vagrant Box

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to setup larave/Homestead. But while installing Homestead Vagrant Box I lost internet connection in middle, later on I tried to reinstall it using '`$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead`'
command line, but it prompts following errors while reinstalling.

```
1) virtualbox
2) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 1
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.3.3) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.3.3/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
```

I tried reinstalling vagrant but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Nicklas for your quick response. But I solved it adding '-c' flag at end.

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead -c
```

This removed files associated with it allocated in .vagrant.d/tmp/

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the temporary files generated by Vagrant.

This can be achieved in three ways:

1. **Force Clean Install**

   Add a parameter `--clean` as such `$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead --clean`
2. **Manual Deletion**

   Navigate manually to vagrants temporary folder, by hitting `cmd+space` and typing `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/`, and remove files located there.
3. **Terminal**

   Open the terminal and remove the temporary files generated by
   vagrant:

   ```
   rm ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to force the installer to clean the old files, so you just need to use this command

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead --clean
```

[source](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/box.html)